# How to print output of training data in a keras model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

What I'm doing is training a model with a dataset containing 318 rows and 6 attributes.7th is the target output(only 1 or 0) .I just want the model to print 1 or 0 i.e output of the model. I have trained the model as shown in the code below and got accuracy of 90%. But I couldn't figure out how to get those output values for each of the training data. Is there any way to print or generate a new csv file containing the predicted output for the training data? 
For e.g.:
Target(7th attribute): 1 0 0 Predicted(model output): 1 0 1
Help would be great.Thanks!

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy

# random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(2)

# loading heart dataset
dataset = numpy.loadtxt("heartorig1.csv", delimiter=",")

# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables, splitting csv data
X = dataset[:,0:6]
Y = dataset[:,6]

# split X, Y into a train and test set
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2,       random_state=42)

# create model, add dense layers one by one specifying activation function
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=6, activation='relu')) # input layer requires       input_dim param
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) # sigmoid instead of relu for final probability between 0 and 1

# compile the model, adam gradient descent (optimized)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])

# call the function to fit to the data (training the network)
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 1000, batch_size=20, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))


# save the model
model.save('weights2.h5')
```

Comment: Do you mean [`model.predict`](https://keras.io/models/model/#predict)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just call `model.predict()` on your training data after training it:

`model.predict(x_train)`

This will give you a numpy array with predicted class probabilities. To convert to binary values, apply a threshold to the probabilities and cast them to integers:
`(model.predict(x_train) > 0.5).astype(int)`